# RewriteCond giving false positive if part of URL points to existing file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I set up a .htaccess file to route requests for my site:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Requests for existing files (like images) are handled normally, others are forwarded to the router. This works fine.

I am trying to get the following type of URLs to work for viewing thumbnails:

```
http://www.example.com/images/image.png/thumbnail-big/
```

The idea being that `http://www.example.com/images/image.png` is a valid URL, and points to a file, but the thumbnail variant isn't a valid URL (because of the `/thumbnail-big/` part), and is handled by the router (which generates a thumbnail, if needed).

But this doesn't work. The thumbnail URL is handled as if pointing to an existing file, and the RewriteRule for the router is skipped, but it isn't an actual file, so the server displays a generic 404 error. In other words, the "is this path an existing file" condition apparently evaluates to true for the thumbnail URL, even though it is not an existing file. It's almost as if only the part up till `image.png` is evaluated.

Is there a way to check whether the file exists in such a way that I don't get this false positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your conditions and rule to this:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Use of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` can be misguiding sometimes as the way file name is generated internally by Apache. In your case it is checking for file with the address as: `http://www.example.com/images/image.png`